# How can I get TypeScript to work with jQuery Plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, typescript

I've got a jQuery plugin that works in the standard way:

```
$.fn.doSomething = function () {
//do something to each item in the list
}
```

In regular javascript, I can then invoke `doSomething` as if it were really part of jQuery:

```
$(selector).doSomething();
```

Typescript using the `jquery.d.ts` reference works fine with jQuery, but doesn't know anything about my plugin, and so I get:

```
The property 'doSomething' does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'.
```

So how do I tell TypeScript about the additional functionality that I added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a typings definition file for the plugin.

Some common libraries are available here(and through nuget)   https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

You may want to search google to see if yours is already made by someone. If not, you just need to make your own.

For example, if I wanted to be able to do `$('#idOfElement').autosize();`

I would create a .d.ts file containing this code:

```
interface JQuery {
    autosize(): JQuery;
}
```

Or maybe auto size takes some options, in which case you could define it like this:

```
interface JQuery {
    autosize(): JQuery;
    autosize(options: autosizeOptions): JQuery;
}

interface autosizeOptions {
    className?: string;
    append?: string;
    callback?: any;
}
```

Comment: That totally worked, thanks!  I didn't realize that interfaces in TypeScript are partial, and you can just add another `interface JQuery` with some new members and Typescript will combine them into one interface.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank When I first started with typescript I didn't realize it either,it's an easy mistake.I added mine to the jquery.d.ts file, then much later down the road updated my jquery.d.ts through nuget and all my changes were gone =(. Luckily source control saved me there.